# How Change Array Key Values in Foreach Loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I filter the values ​​in the array and create a new array. But the keys in the output are the same. I used the array in a new foreach loop to fix it but gave the same output again.

```
Array ([0] => text1',number,'text2 [1] => text3',number,'text4 [2] => text5',number,'text6)
```

the above example is a series of output `$teams.`

```
foreach ($teams as $key=>$first) {
    $chat = array($first);
    $array = explode("',", $chat[0]);
    $array = explode(",'", $array[0]);
    $redteams = array($array[0]);
    print_r($redteams);
}
```

the output it gave me:

```
 Array ( [0] => text1 ) Array ( [0] => text3 ) Array ( [0] => text5 )
```

it should be an output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => text1 ) Array ( [1] => text3 ) Array ( [2] => text5 )
```

Comment: Do you understand that output is a multidimensional array? I think you are looking for `$redteams[] = $array[0];`

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat, I've tried it before, but the result is not what I want. output: Array ( [0] => text [1] => text ),  Array ( [0] => text [1] => text [2] => text), Array ( [0] => text [1] => text [2] => text [3] => text)

Comment: `$redteams[$i++ ?? 0] = array( $i - 1 => $array[0] );`

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat, gave a similar output.

Comment: The code should work just fine, you have to remove the `print_r` from foreach loop and write it after loop is completed.

Comment: `$redteams[][$key] = $array[0];` - https://eval.in/966465

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat, `$redteams[$i++ ?? 0] = array( $array[0] );` When I changed the code like this, it gave me a close result. Output:  `Array
([0] => Array([0] => text1 [1] => Array([0] => text2)`

Comment: Change it to match my second comment.

Comment: I've tried.But the present output is enough for me.Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @splash58, Thank you for your comment. I solved it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this

```
array_values($redteams);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved it in a different way.